# finding reverse dependencies of package on `hackage`

Tags: haskell, hackage

The website [packdeps](https://packdeps.haskellers.com) allows to search for reverse dependencies of libraries published on hackage.

However, not every package from hackage seem to be listed there, say [algebraic-classes](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/algebraic-classes)

Is there any alternative way to find the reverse dependencies of a generic hackage package ?

Comment: I suspect `algebraic-classes` doesn't have reverse dependencies on Hackage. Executable-only packages, which have no reverse dependencies, also don't seem to show up in that list (`aura` is the first example that comes to mind).

Comment: you are probably right...